# Get python list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to create over flowing pythonic list meaning that if i'm trying to get the index of list even if the index is larger then then the list size.

if the index is bigger then the list size I want to get the index from the start of the list.

for example if the list size is 5

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

so `l[7]` should return `3` [index 2]

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question about this? Why don't you simply use an `if` statement?

Comment: If `l[7]` should return `2`, what should `l[5]` return?

Comment: `l[7]` should return `3`, python uses `0` based indexing

Comment: If i understand correctly your answer, i think this can be your solution `i[7-(len(i))]`. Python also starting the indexing from `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `%` (modulo) operator to handle this type of situation, and I'll assume that you meant `l[7]` should return `3` (at index `2` in the list). A functional solution:

```
def overflow_index(l, idx):
    return l[idx % len(l)]

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(overflow_index(L, 7))  # Output: 3
```

An object-oriented solution, defining subclass of `list` and overriding its `__getitem__` method which handles subscript access, i.e. `l[7]`:

```
class OverflowList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return super().__getitem__(idx % len(self))


OL = OverflowList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(OL[7])  # Output: 3
```

The `super().__getitem__` function refers to the builtin `list`'s method, which needs to be called to prevent infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear:

suppose:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

l[0] is 1
l[1] is 2
and so on...
```

You can do a `forloop` to print all the values:

```
for x in range(len(l)):
   print(l[x])
```

Now if you want to plug in large values in x you can use `mod operator %`

```
l[x%len(l)]
```

here x can be any large number.

```
when x=7:

l[7%len(l)]
#output
3

when x=5:

l[5%len(l)]
#output
1
```